# Pointer Wrong Return Value

Tags: c++, pointers

Does anyone know why y = 11?
It's 21/12 = 1.75, but however it returns 11.

```
int i=3, j=5, *p = &i, *q = &j, *r;
int y = 7 **p / *q + 7;
```

Comment: It's code from my school textbook :)

Comment: @JesseStruyvelt - I hope the paper is absorbent. That is the only use for that book as toilet paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
7 * *p / *q + 7
7 * (3) / (5) + 7   Substitution
21 / 5 + 7
4 + 7               Integer Division
11
```

Comment: Wow, don't know how I could have forgotten that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations.  7 * 3 / 5 + 7 is 21/5 + 7. Since you're using ints, that's 4 + 7 = 11.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence - using brackets to denote the order of evaluation:

```
int y = ((7 * *p) / *q) + 7;
```

> 7 * 3 / 5 = 4
>
> 4+  7 = 11

Answer (score 1):

All operations are done as integer and not as floating point operations.

Let's take this apart

```
7 * (*p) / (*q) + 7
7 *  *&i /  *&j + 7
7 *   3  /   5  + 7
21       /   5  + 7
4               + 7
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Its correct, your expression evaluates to :

```
(7* 3)/5  + 7

= 4 + 7
```

which is equal to 11